# Como borrar un texto en especifico en una archivo txt en Python

Tags: python, txt

Buenas  Mi duda es que tengo que realizar un programa que permita crear, modificar y eliminar textos en un archivo txt además de hacer búsquedas y filtrar, lo realice mediante expresiones regulares con la función re para todo lo que es la búsqueda de textos que digite el usuario, el problema que tengo ahorita es al borrar un texto ya que no logro que me borre el texto que es y supongo que es por la posición del cursor dentro del archivo txt y no logro hacer que me ponga el cursor en la posición donde este el texto a borrar, si alguien me podria ayudar y explicar que puede ser, me serviría mucho gracias.

Codigó:

```
from io import open
import re
def Menu():
 print('******MENU AGENDAS****')
 print('1.- Ver lista')
 print('2.- Ver lista filtrada')
 print('3.- Añadir un beneficiario')
 print('4.- Buscar un beneficiario')
 print('5.- Eliminar un beneficiario')
 print('6.- Salir')
 print()
opcionmenu = 0
Menu()
x=0
while opcionmenu != 6:
 opcionmenu = int(input("Ingresa la opcion deseada: "))
 if opcionmenu == 1:
    agenda_texto=open("agenda.txt","r")
    texto=agenda_texto.read()
    agenda_texto.close()
    print("Listado Completo: ")
    print(texto)
    Menu() ## Llama la funcion menu
 elif opcionmenu == 2:
    agenda_texto=open("agenda.txt","r")
    lineas_texto=agenda_texto.readlines()
    agenda_texto.close()
    print("Inserte la letra inicial del beneficiario")
    letra=input()
    for elemento in lineas_texto:
        if re.match(letra, elemento):
            print(elemento)
    Menu()
 elif opcionmenu == 3:
    print("¿Va a crear la agenda por primera vez?, pulse S si es así o N si no")
    decision=input()
    if decision=="S" or decision=="s":
        agenda_texto=open("agenda.txt","w")
        print("Digite nombre del beneficiario, identificación y numero de telefono")
        nombre=input()
        identicacion=input()
        numero=input()
        agenda_texto.write(nombre + " ")
        agenda_texto.write(identicacion + " ")
        agenda_texto.write(numero + "\n")
        agenda_texto.close()
        Menu()
    else:
        agenda_texto=open("agenda.txt", "r+")
        print("Digite nombre del beneficiario, identificación y numero de telefono")
        nombre=input()
        lineas_texto=agenda_texto.readlines()
        identicacion=input()
        for elemento2 in lineas_texto:
            while re.search(identicacion, elemento2):
                print("La identificacion ya existe, intente de nuevo")
                identicacion=input()
        numero=input()
        agenda_texto.write(nombre + " ")
        agenda_texto.write(identicacion + " ")
        agenda_texto.write(numero + "\n")
        agenda_texto.close()
        Menu()
 elif opcionmenu == 4:
    agenda_texto=open("agenda.txt","r")
    lineas_texto=agenda_texto.readlines()
    agenda_texto.close()
    print("Inserte el nombre del beneficiario a buscar")
    letra=input()
    for elemento3 in lineas_texto:
        if re.findall(letra, elemento3):
            print(elemento3)
    Menu()
 elif opcionmenu == 5:
    agenda_texto=open("agenda.txt","r+")
    lineas_texto=agenda_texto.readlines()
    print("Inserte el nombre del beneficiario a borrar")
    letra=input()
    for elemento4 in lineas_texto:
        if re.findall(letra, elemento4):
            print("Esta seguro que desea borrar el beneficiario: ", elemento4, " pulse S si es asi o N si no")
            peticion=input()
            if peticion=="S" or peticion=="s":
                cambio=elemento4.replace(elemento4, "Borrado")
                print(cambio)
                posi=elemento4.find(letra)
                print(posi)
                agenda_texto.seek(posi)
                agenda_texto.writelines(cambio + cambio + cambio)
            else:
                Menu()
    agenda_texto.close()
    Menu()
 elif opcionmenu != 6:
     Menu()
```

Comment: Lo más fácil es abrir el archivo de salida y guardar todo el contenido actualizado del texto. O sea, reemplazar el archivo con una nueva versión.

Comment: Lo mejor sería volcar una copia de todo el texto en una estructura un poco más amigable, como puede ser una lista o un diccionario. Será mucho más sencillo ubicar elementos en alguna de estas estructuras que intentar ubicarlo mediante la lectura secuencial del archivo. Una vez que has modificado tu lista o diccionario solo escribes ("salvas") el archivo reemplazando su contenido previo por el de la estructura modificada, todo esto asumiendo que nadie más ha modificado el archivo antes o durante todo el proceso.

Comment: Utiliza la función `seek()` para moverte en el archivo

Comment: Christian ya intente lo del seek() como puedes ver en el codigo pero es dificil decirle donde tiene que poner el cursor

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por sus comentarios, ya logre resolver el problema.

La solución que aplique fue la siguiente:

```
agenda_texto=open("agenda.txt","r+")
lineas_texto=agenda_texto.readlines()
agenda_texto.close()
print("¿Esta seguro que desea borrar algún dato?, Pulse S si es así o cualquier tecla si no")
peticion=input()
if peticion=="S" or peticion=="s":
    print(lineas_texto)
    print("Seleccione el dato iniciando desde 0")
    elegir=int(input())
    lineas_texto.remove(lineas_texto[elegir])
    agenda_texto=open("agenda.txt","w")
    agenda_texto.writelines(lineas_texto)
    agenda_texto.close()
else:
    Menu()
Menu()
```

Comment: Listo Christian, Gracias por la recomendación, estaba tan emocionado que no me di cuenta jaja

Comment: como sugerencia, en vez de pedirle que ingrese el dato iniciando desde `0`, solo pide el dato *normal* y le restas 1 (`-1`) así será mejor para el usuario :)

Comment: Hola Christian, eh intente que el usuario escribiera el nombre como tal, pero no funciono tal vez tenia que escribirlo igual y no te entiendo lo del -1

Comment: `elegir=int(input())-1` y solo le pides que ingrese el numero de la linea, ósea `print("Seleccione el dato")`